# Magento 2: How to remove decimal from cost price in catalog grid

Tags: price, magento2.2.3

I want to remove 2 decimal from cost price in the admin grid.

I want to show 9.61 instead of 9.6100.

[image]

Please let me know any quick fix for this.

Comment: You need to pass 'type'      => 'price' in the column it will definitely work

Comment: Please share the file location

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

Comment: I will use this and check

Comment: yeah find cost column and pass  'type' => 'price'

Comment: Let me know, if it works !

Comment: Hi, did it worked ?

Comment: Not find any grid file where you we find cost field

Comment: <magento.host>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php

Comment: And i think **cost**  is your enhancement so it must be in your custom module, do you have any idea regarding that ?

Comment: cost is the default product attribute, not the grid element

Comment: I tried bro but not able to find it.